# Package python code dependencies for remote execution on the fly

Tags: python, git, ssh, packaging, dill

my situation is as follows, we have:

1. an "image" with all our dependencies in terms of software + our in-house `python` package
2. a "pod" in which such image is loaded on command (kubernetes pod)
3. a `python` project which has some **uncommitted** code of its own which leverages the in-house package
4. Also please assume you cannot work on the machine (or cluster) directly (say remote `SSH` interpreter). the cluster is multi-tenant and we want to optimize it as much as possible so no idle times between trials
5. also for now forget security issues, everything is locked down on our side so no issues there

we want to essentially to "distribute" remotely the workload -i.e. a `script.py` - (unfeasible in our local machines) without being constrained by git commits, therefore being able to do it "on the fly". this is necessary as all of the changes are experimental in nature (think ETL/pipeline kind of analysis): we want to be able to experiment at scale but with no bounds with regards to git.

I tried `dill` but I could not manage to make it work (probably due to the structure of the code). ideally, I would like to replicate the concept `mleap` applied to ML pipelines for `Spark` but on a much smaller scale, basically packaging but with little to no constraints.

What would be the preferred route for this use case?

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  It sounds like you want to push code and dependencies to a distributed server, run some script, and then get results back on the local host.  Is that correct?  This is a workflow that I have built code for (using `dill`, `pathos`, `ppft`, and `pox`) -- it strongly depends on whether you have all of the script's dependencies as installed packages.  You may have to give it some manual directives for each case, depending on the nature of the dependencies.  I'm not sure, from your enumerated list above, what exactly you are dealing with, so I can't be more specific.

Comment: Dill author, what an honour! Your package Is a marvel. The dependencies will be 1:1, fully matched, with the local machine. As for our python package, we would like to keep it as a module (It"s a submodule right now of the project) rather than a package but It will be present 1:1 on both the local and the remote machine. We do not need to retrieve huge chunks of data (just a success/failure kind of message). The in-house package could be installed though if this makes things much easier